# ngFor does not update when new data is sent to the variable of type array

Tags: arrays, angular, variables, ngfor

I am trying to make the page update data through ngFor but it is impossible.
I have two components app.component and secondComponent.

In the app.component there is a button that when pressed activates the change() function in the secondComponent. This function updates an array type variable. The problem arises when the array is updated but not the DOM.

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
 
  data: string = 'A1';
  constructor(private second: SecondComponent) {}

  send() {
    this.second.change(this.data);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p>APP COMPONENT</p>
<button class="button" (click)="send()">Push</button>

<secondComponent-app></secondComponent-app>
```

**secondComponent.ts**

```
export class SecondComponent {
  box1: any = ['car', 'plane'];

  change(data) {
    if (data == 'A1') {
      this.box1 = ['car1', 'plane1'];
    }

    console.log(this.box1);
  }
}
```

**secondComponent.html**

```
<p>SECOND COMPONENT</p>
<div *ngFor="let item of box1 ">{{item}}</div>
```

Can anybody help me?. Thanks in advance.
See StackBlitz  https://angular-ivy-qbeqzo.stackblitz.io/

Comment: I think you creae a problem that should not exist. This is not the correct approach to do it, and this results in issues that should not arise. Try using @Input() and  @Output() and see if it resolves the issues by itself.

Answer (score 1):

In your parent component's constructor, Angular is injecting an instance of your `SecondComponent` (it would seem) that is a different instance than the one in your component's template specified by `<secondComponent-app>`

Instead of putting it into the constructor, do the following:

1. Add an angular identifier to your child component tag (denoted by a `#`), e.g. `<secondComponent-app #second>`
2. Use `@ViewChild` to gain access to the component in the template in your parent's class body like so:

```
export class AppComponent {
 
  data: string = 'A1';
  @ViewChild('second', { static: true }) second: SecondComponent;
```

You should then be able to handle the `SecondComponent` as a field of your parent.

More info: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: Great, I've been trying to figure it out for 5 hours. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank glad it was helpful. There are "Angular ways" of having two components communicate. This is the typical parent-to-child method. You may need other ways in the future. See https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction